# How can I restart a race in GTA V story mode before it's finished?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

while racing in GTA V story mode, I often find myself in a situation where I'm behind on the rest and I managed to screw up a checkpoint, leading to a situation where I cannot get back into first place before the race is over. In such a situation, I'd rather just restart the race entirely. However, I cannot find an easy way to do so, apart from failing it through skipping a checkpoint. Is there an easier way to restart a race, like through a menu option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no restart option for missions (racing counts as a mission), apart from saving before you start and then loading the game.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is look for an NPC car that's not in the race. When you steal their car, it ends the mission in failure right away.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to force a restart by wrecking or otherwise destroying your vehicle.